# PHP - Best practice for passing in object into another class?

Tags: php

Assume I have the following classes: `Attributes`, `Quote` given:

```
    class Attributes {
         private $attr1; 

         public function __construct($attr)
         {
              // implementation 
         }

   }

   class Quote {
       private $obj;

       public function __construct($id, $obj)
       {
           $this->obj = $obj;  
           var_dump($this->obj); 
       }
   }
```

Can I therefore, somehow, pass in the object to the constructor for `Quote`, like this:

```
$attr = new Attributes("1");
$quote = new Quote(1, $attr);
```

Doing this, just gives me a blank page?

Comment: enable error reporting to see the php errors?

Comment: I just tested your code and not getting any error here's the out put `object(Attributes)#1 (1) { ["attr1":"Attributes":private]=> NULL } `

Comment: @HardikBhavsar - Here is a full example: http://ideone.com/TBusbx

Comment: @Phorce : you can't Cannot access protected property Attributes::$intro, it's give me fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're trying to access the variables directly. You can either make the variables public or you can write get functions in your Attributes class.

Also you made a typing mistake in your full example ;)

Answer (score 0):

See **PHP: Visibility :**http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php for details on the difference between private, protected and public.

Here's your code :

```
<?php
    session_start();

    class Attributes {

        public $intro;
        protected $column1;
        protected $column2;
        protected $cost;
        protected $dateValid;
        protected $TAC;

        public function __construct($theIntro, $theColumn, $theColumn2, $theCost, $theDateValid, $theTAC)
        {
            $this->intro   = $theIntro;
            $this->column1 = $theColumn;
            $this->column2 = $theColumn2;
            $this->cost    = $theCost;
            $this->dateValid = $theDateValid;
            $this->TAC = $theTAC;
        }
    }

    class Quote {

        private $QuoteID;
        private $attr;

        public function __construct($id, $obj)
        {
            $this->attr = $obj;
            $this->QuoteID = $id;

            echo $this->attr->intro; 

            var_dump($this->attr->intro);
        }



    }


$attr = new Attributes("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
$quote = new Quote("1", $attr); 
?>
```